# How to ensure that DataProvider is initialized only once WITHOUT using Factory?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a test class in which all the methods use the same DataProvider. I want the DataProvider to be parallelized. I cannot use the Factory method because there is a [defect](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/751) in TestNg which makes it useless for my purpose.

Right now, the data provider is re-computed for each method that uses it. Using a factory would fix this problem except that I need all the methods in each instance of the test class spawned by the factory to be run in the SAME thread. There is an outstanding defect with TestNG where parallel-by-instance is not working. I have tried using older versions of TestNG, but every version I tried has the defect. I can only go so far back before I start losing other features I need.

I also need for the DataProvider to run in parallel -- that is, all methods in the test class should be run in parallel for each of the sets of data provided. Is there some workaround I can use to ensure that the DataProvider is initialized just once AND the provider is multi-threaded?

Another wrinkle is that when I use a parallel DataProvider without a Factory, each test method is run in a separate thread. What I want is for ALL methods in the test class to be run in the SAME thread for each dataset in the provider and for each dataset to be executed in parallel. So, if I have three datasets, I want three threads in which the test methods in the class are executed.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to propose a pull-request with the fix of the issue you pointed. 
Otherwise, you can manage the problem yourself by having a static attribute and by returning it after the first call (and its initialization). 
You can have an external data provider class too, where you can initialize in the constructor by default.

Comment: So, I downloaded the source for TestNg to take a try at figuring out how to fix this defect. Where, exactly, should I be looking because I am having trouble figuring out where the test methods are scheduled for a given thread. It doesn't help that I was one of the many students who got lost in Data Structures once graph algorithms got introduced....

Comment: A good start is to add a new test that shows the problem, and propose it. Then, it will be simplier to discuss about how to fix it. BTW, did you try the workarrounds?

Comment: I have a workaround that is ugly, but does the job. I created a data manager class that uses a hashmap to manage the data. The key value isthe hashcode of the WebDriver instances that are used for each of the datasets provisioned by the DataProvider. I'll create that test before the end of the week.